# Java - Find occurrences of substring in a string

Tags: java

Say I had a string

```
String s = "foofoo bar barbarbar foo
```

and I wanted to find all the occurrences of `foo` and print them out like so:

```
foo foo foo
```

I've already looked into `StringUtils`, but it seems to me (an amateur) that this library is only able to count the *number* of occurrences of `foo`. Is there something I'm doing wrong here? Or is regex really the best way to go?

Comment: Once you've found the number of occurances, just loop that number of times writing "foo " on each loop.

Answer (score -1):

You can use indexOf method of String class and substring method of the same class to achieve the desired result, but using regex it would be less typing and easier to implement. I have provided a possible solution for you below

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class Sample {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "foofoo bar barbarbar foo";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("foo");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.print(m.group() + " ");
    }
}
}
```